# Remoção de espaços em branco em excesso

Tags: string, advpl

Como remover espaços em branco dentro de uma *string*?

Seria no sentido de remover os espaços de uma cadeia de texto, com exceção dos espaços simples entre palavras, como é na função "arrumar" do Excel.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 9):

A função [`AllTrim()`](http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/AllTrim) resolve a maioria dos casos. Se desejar que elimine no meio:

```
Function MiddleTrim(cText)
    Local cClean := ""
    Local cLast := " "
    Local nLen := Len(cText)
    Local i
    Local cChar
    For i := 1 To nLen
        cChar := Substr(cText, i, 1)
        If cChar != " "
            cClean += cChar
        ElseIf cLast != " "
            cClean += " "
        EndIf
        cLast := cChar
    Next
    If Substr(cClean, Len(cClean), 1) == " "
        cClean := Substr(cClean, 1, Len(cClean) - 1)
    EndIf
Return cClean
```

Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ADVPLMiddleTrim.prg).

Desta forma lê caractere por caractere identificando se já existia um espaço antes, só copia o caractere se não for espaço ou se for o espaço imediatamente seguinte a um não espaço, ou seja, fica apenas um espaço. Como pode ficar um último espaço no final, ele limpa também. Percorrer caractere por caractere é o que o `StrTran()` **e** o `AllTrim()` fariam, por isso tem chance de ser mais eficiente desta forma por percorrer só uma vez.

No Harbour talvez não porque ele seria executado em C de forma bem eficiente. Não sei como está hoje, mas ADVPL tinha implementação bem ineficiente em muitas coisas, tanto que alguns recursos comuns no Harbour ou mesmo Clipper até recomendam evitar o uso.

Comment: Para eliminar os espaços no meio, acredito que o `StrTran(cText, " ")` seja mais simples

Comment: Aí tira todos espaços.

Comment: Ok, porém mais fácil verificar se existe um espaço no final e/ou começo, usar o strtran, e depois adicionar se precisar. Aí executa direto no servidor de aplicação, e não via advpl.

Comment: Tenta fazer assim. Não dá o resultado desejado na pergunta. Faz tempo que não mexo na plataforma, não sei como está essa questão do servidor de aplicação e por isso não entendi o que quis dizer com isso, pode me explicar?

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa:

```
Function MiddleTrim(cText)
    While "  " $ cText
        cText = StrTran(cText, "  ", " ")
    End
    Return AllTrim(cText)
```

Lembrando que apesar de mais curta que a resposta do @Maniero (que já recebeu meu +1), ela não necessariamente seja mais performática, pois pode percorrer a *string* várias vezes.

Pontos de interesse:

- `StrTran(cText, "  ", " ")` troca ocorrências de dois espaços por um só. Mas como a função não é recursiva, precisa de um *loop*;
- `While "  " $ cText` faz o loop enquanto `"  "` estiver contindo em cText;
- Finalmente o `AllTrim` remove os espaços das "pontas" da *string*.

Nota:

Tomei por base a sintaxe do Harbour, se houver alguma diferença em Advpl provavelmente vai ser só um ajuste no `While .. End`. O relevante aqui é a lógica.